# Bootstrap/JavaScript/jQuery - modal not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an [almost empty] Bootstrap modal implemented as JavaScript/template pair.

.modal('show') doesn't seem to do anything. No error message is displayed, either.

The code is below. The data to this modal comes from another element (#constructionList), and the data is received fine as is seen in debug. In fact, everything up to `$('#constructionFinancialsDialogModal').modal('show');` seems to be working fine.

JavaScript:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'parse',
  'js/models/construction',
  'js/models/constructionfinancials',
  'js/collections/constructions',
  'text!templates/construction/constructionFinancialsDialog.html'
  ], function ($, _, Parse, Construction, ConstructionFinancials, Constructions, ConstructionFinancialsDialog) {

    var ConstructionFinancialsDialogView = Parse.View.extend({
      template: _.template(ConstructionFinancialsDialog),

      el: ".constructionFinancialsDialogModal",

      initialize: function() {
        this.render();
        return this;
      },

      events: {
        "click .close": "close",
        "click .cancel": "close",
        "hidden.bs.modal #constructionFinancialsDialogModal": "close",
        "click .authorizePayout": "authorizePayout"
      },

      render: function() {
        var data = {};
        var constructionsTable = $('#constructionsList').dataTable();

        data.typeOfAction = 'Display';
        data.buttonType = 'Authorize Payout';
        this.$el.html(this.template(data));

        $('#constructionFinancialsDialogModal').modal('show');          
        return this;
      },

      authorizePayout: function(){
        that = this;
        var obj = {};
      }
    });

    return ConstructionFinancialsDialogView;
  });
```

Template:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="constructionFinancialsDialogModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="constructionFinancialsDialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 id="financialsLabel" class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-money "></i> <%=typeOfAction%> Construction Financials</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 pull-right text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-white dim cancel"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancel</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dim authorizePayout"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> <%=buttonType%></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="alert alert-danger" id="payoutErrorMsgContainer" style="display: none;"></div>
                <div class="alert alert-success" id="payoutInfoMsgContainer" style="display: none;"></div>
                <div class="row"> 
                    Future financials dialog    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                Footer content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the modal wrapped in any other DOM element? Can you open the modal from the console directly by `$('#constructionFinancialsDialogModal').modal();` ?

Comment: `$('#constructionFinancialsDialogModal').modal();` 
from console returns [] and nothing is happening. 

Same goes for `$('#constructionFinancialsDialogModal').modal('show');`

Comment: It returns `[]`? So `$('#constructionFinancialsDialogModal').length` is `0`?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed `0`

Comment: So the modal isn't in the DOM - you need to make sure it's been included somewhere. If it's in your DOM, maybe it's being overwritten by something else? Can you show us more of the HTML code?

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you for the idea.

Template of parent view was missing declaration <div class="constructionFinancialsDialogModal"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Template of parent view was missing declaration of this modal.

`<div class="constructionFinancialsDialogModal"></div>`